# WMI query local administrators including group members

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wmic, wql

I know how to fetch a list of local administrators on a remote machine via WMI:

`wmic /Node:"ComputerName" path win32_groupuser where (groupcomponent="win32_group.name=\"administrators\",domain=\"Computername\"")`

This will return users and groups:

`GroupComponent                                          PartComponent
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="Computername",Name="Administrator"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="Domain Admins"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="SomeOtherGroup"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="MyUser"`

However, if a user is a member of `SomeOtherGroup` above, I need to know that he is a member - and therefore a local admin. So, I need to expand (likely recursively) all group members.

Is there a WMI query that can self-join on `win32_group`, expanding all usernames of all groups that are local admins?

Answer (score 1):

There is [`ASSOCIATORS OF` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384793(v=vs.85).aspx) in the [WMI Query Language (WQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The `ASSOCIATORS OF` statement retrieves all instances that are
>   associated with a particular source instance. The instances that are
>   retrieved are referred to as the endpoints. Each endpoint is returned
>   as many times as there are associations between it and the source
>   object.

The following VBScript should do the job:

```
option explicit

Function wmiGroupMembers( sGroupName, intLevel)
  Dim colSubGroups, colSubGroup, sQuery

  sQuery = "Associators of {win32_group.domain=""" & sDomainName & _
                                      """,name=""" & sGroupName & """} " _
        & "Where ResultRole = PartComponent"

  Set colSubGroups = objWMIService.ExecQuery( sQuery )
  For Each colSubGroup in colSubGroups
    If LCase( colSubGroup.Path_.Class) = "win32_group" Then
      wmiGroupMembers colSubGroup.Name, intLevel + 1
    End If 
    sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & intLevel _
                          & vbTab & sGroupName _
                          & vbTab & colSubGroup.Domain _
                          & vbTab & colSubGroup.Name
  Next
End Function

Dim sResult, wshNetwork, sComputerName, sDomainName, objWMIService
sResult = ""
Set wshNetwork    = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
    sComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
    sDomainName   = UCase( wshNetwork.UserDomain)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputerName & "\root\cimv2")

wmiGroupMembers "administrators", 0

Wscript.Echo sResult
```

Note that although there is a `wmic` equivalent (see [`ASSOC` verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx)), it's usage could be a tough problem as all output from any `cmd` utility is text (i.e. not objects) and must be parsed using [`for` loop command](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).